# unable to relay - exchange server 2013

Tags: windows, exchange

I was configuring exchange server 2013. But while sending test mails getting error "unable to relay". I have tested using telnet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you actually need to be able to relay on this server? Actual Exchange users using Outlook/OMA/Mobile Access/etc will be authenticated and should be able to send fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Exchange Admin Center to create a Receive Connector for whichever services need to send email through your mail server.

1. Open EAC
2. Navigate to **Mail Flow > Receive Connectors**. Click on **Add+**
3. Select **Internal** if it is for internal email.

Configure permissions as needed and specify the IP addresses/range for the sending hosts.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to relay - you need to create a receive connector.
On that connector specify ipaddress/range of the relaying server and choose authentication model.